# Where are the docker containers stored on my fedora host machine?

Tags: docker, centos, redhat, fedora

Where are the docker containers stored on my fedora host machine?
Below is my disk space when I have started 3 containers. The total disk space is 1.3T. When I should open again another container, my total disk space would be 1.4T, etc. My ssd drive is not that large. So what is going on? When another 99G is added, other numbers are not going down.

```
[root@almond docker]# df --total -h
Filesystem               Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                 7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /dev
tmpfs                    7.8G  379M  7.5G   5% /dev/shm
tmpfs                    7.8G  2.4M  7.8G   1% /run
tmpfs                    7.8G     0  7.8G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/mapper/fedora-root   50G   37G   11G  79% /
tmpfs                    7.8G  2.2M  7.8G   1% /tmp
/dev/sda1                477M  176M  273M  40% /boot
/dev/mapper/fedora-home  860G   45G  772G   6% /home
tmpfs                    1.6G   16K  1.6G   1% /run/user/42
tmpfs                    1.6G  5.2M  1.6G   1% /run/user/1000
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/0
tmpfs                    1.6G     0  1.6G   0% /run/user/26
/dev/dm-4                 99G  668M   93G   1%       /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/9b57a4483a4358dbd75e4a0bb3524da4b0db394f63875f90818daf4f47ab60c6
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/d3a82943e6d0cf286395a3195eb191430e03e1d48571525a0c40238b0f6c6b1e/shm
/dev/dm-5                 99G  640M   93G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/0a902b9a051b8718caae02c87a688f3646bb01e8906efbd60b03a76085613d9a
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/0da780053f389c67e8054487643f4e61faec83228ab0e130e736b28876619b27/shm
/dev/dm-6                 99G  640M   93G   1% /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/21bcf6fc14430e5e5d817a5de069e0aeaceb7c32dc125b3b1c2056060e5a79c7
shm                       64M     0   64M   0% /var/lib/docker/containers/96ff5e4e5d58296821da90e78bb94b714268f661b7b4163272148ca2f8e3a06e/shm

total                    1.3T   84G  1.1T   7% -
```

Comment: I’d suggest looking at this output that `df --total` is not producing a useful result: even ignoring the artificial Docker lines it’s clearly multiple-counting things.  There are very strong very Googleable hints in the last couple of filesystem lines.

Comment: containers are stored in /var/lib/docker/containers as shown in your output. That said, what numbers do you want to go down? Also, if you are using devicemapper, read docs about it. https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/device-mapper-driver/

Comment: @techtabu I don't know. Those 99G must come from somewhere. So on top of the list, some Avails should go down.

Comment: It's total space, why do you expect it to go down? Is this your personal machine or are you looking at a shared machine/ VM? Somebody must have set up that device mapper settings. I use ubuntu, but I don't see separate size for docker volumes, just the size of my hard disk on total column.